# Rxjs - clean up observable after subscriber unsubscribes

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm using a library that doesn't support rxjs, just good ol' callbacks. I'm trying to wrap it in an observable but I need the inner stream to dispose of itself when someone unsubscribes.

```
subscribeToQuotes() {
    return new Observable(observer => {

        const stream = someLibrary.getStream();

        stream.onNewData(data => {
            observer.next(data);
        });
        stream.onComplete(() => observer.complete());

        const request = stream.begin(); 

        //I need to call request.abort() when subscriber unsubscribes
    })
}
```

I want to use this as such:

```
    const onInstrumentChanged = new Subject();

    onInstrumentChanged.subscribe(instrument => {

        this.subscribeToQuotes(instrument)
            .pipe(takeUntil(onInstrumentChanged))
            .subscribe(quotes => {
                ...
            })


    })
```

`subscribeToQuotes()` can get called multiple times, and the `takeUntil()` drops the previous subscription, however the inner stream keeps firing. I need to call `request.abort()` internally.

**How can I call `request.abort()` when the subject `onInstrumentChanged` fires?**

Can this be done without passing the subject into the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer.  `observer.add()` allows you to add a teardown function for when the subscriber unsubscribes. So in my case this works:

```
    return new Observable(observer => {

        const stream = someLibrary.getStream();        
        const request = stream.begin(); 
        observer.add(() => request.abort());
    })
```